nodejs http response boundary stream write to file
By extracting the boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
and saving it to file, it turns out to be corrupt.
The same operation with other languages (java , .net) works correctly.
Result file encoding
correct: windows-1252
corrupted: utf8
HEX
correct: 0x30, 0x82
corrupted: 0x30, 0xC2, 0x82
